# How can I make downloaded files appear in "Recent" in Finder?

Tags: macos

I'd like files downloaded via browser to also appear in "Recent" in Finder, as well as the normal content there. I really miss this functionality from Ubuntu and am aware of how much time and clicks it costs to not have it. How can that be achieved?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question so is off-topic here. You might have better luck on https://superuser.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Recent folder is not connected with download folder. But you can drag download folder to the dock, then right click on folder and choose your settings you want.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, but I found out how to fix it. Go to the `download` folder, and then on the menu bar above click “View”, and then click show “Menu” option. Finally, on the “Sort by” section, select “Date added”.

[image: here's some screenshots]